# How to make my Edit and Delete Image functionality in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to implement `onEditPost` and `onDeletePost` inside of my `RecyclerViewFragment`:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.MainActivity
import com.example.projectdrivemark.R
import com.example.projectdrivemark.databinding.FragmentListBinding
import com.example.projectdrivemark.databinding.PostBinding

class RecyclerViewFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_list), PostAdapter.OnPostClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentListBinding
    val dummyList = MockDatabase.createMockData()
    val adapter = PostAdapter(dummyList, this)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycleViewMain).apply{
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
            adapter = PostAdapter(dummyList, this@RecyclerViewFragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onEditPost(position: Int){
        val clickedPost = dummyList[position]
        clickedPost.title = "Updated title"
        clickedPost.body = "Updated body"
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    override fun onDeletePost(position: Int) {
        dummyList.removeAt(position)
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }
}
```

Here is how my `Adapter` looks like:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.MainActivity
import com.example.projectdrivemark.R

class PostAdapter(val dummyData: ArrayList<Post>, val myListener: OnPostClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>() {

    inner class PostViewHolder(postView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(postView), View.OnClickListener{
        val iconImage: ImageView = postView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_view)
        val title: TextView = postView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        val body: TextView = postView.findViewById(R.id.body)
        val deleteIcon: ImageView = postView.findViewById(R.id.delete_post_image)
        val editIcon: ImageView = postView.findViewById(R.id.edit_post_image)

        init {
            deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(this)
            editIcon.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?){
            val position = adapterPosition
            if(v?.id == editIcon.id){
                myListener.onEditPost(position)
            }else{
                myListener.onDeletePost(position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        val postView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false)
        return PostViewHolder(postView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentPost = dummyData[position]
        holder.iconImage.setImageResource(currentPost.image)
        holder.title.text = currentPost.title
        holder.body.text = currentPost.body
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dummyData.size
    }

    interface OnPostClickListener{
        fun onEditPost(position: Int)
        fun onDeletePost(position: Int)
    }
}
```

And here is how my `XML File Post` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_image_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_ac_unit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Title of blog post"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon_image_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Body of first blog post"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.050"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon_image_view" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:gravity="end">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/edit_post_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_post_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_forever" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you see in the `RecyclerViewFragment`, I have 2 functions that is `onEditPost` and `onDeletePost`. I want that functionality to work when I press it. Right now, it only works when I press and change the `fragment view`. I want it to work instantly. If anyone see my mistake or Am I missing something? please do tell me. All help is appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `Adapter` twice, you already have an `Adapter` initialised globally use it in `onViewCreated` instead of assign again. because you are using global adapter to notify changes.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycleViewMain).apply{
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
        adapter = this@RecyclerViewFragment.adapter
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @rajan.kali, I want to ask why use "This@RecyclerViewFrgament"?

Comment: because if you user adapter, it will refer to adapter in recyclerview, and this scope referes to recycler view inside apply, so to get adapter from fragment, you need to do this@Fragment